# Javascript carousel/slider with customizable navgation

Tags: javascript, slider

I am currently developing a site and have a need for a javascript-based carousel/slider hybrid on the home page that fades between 3 or 4 different images automatically, giving the user the chance to click on one and go to another page on the site. I also need the different slides to have some sort of navigation, denoted either by names for each slide (like in the Coda slider effect) or by symbols (such as dots for each slide), to allow users to review their options before clicking on the slide to visit the particular highlighted section.

I have seen this done in many ways with flash , but the only javascript approach I have seen that meets my needs is the one used by Apple on the new iLife page ([link](http://www.apple.com/ilife/)). Does anyone have any ideas what they are using or if there is a project that is similar to their implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the navigation on iLife looks like a photo gallery where the large photo links to the destination. I've used the [jQuery Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) for photo galleries because the animation effects are superb. Also the forum provides helpful community-based support.

If you wanted a carousel-style animation with the images sliding left and right, might try the [jQuery Carousel](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html) library. I have not used it myself though so cannot comment on its ease-of-use or quality.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate or [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Answer (score 0):

The [YUI Carousel Control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/carousel) would be another starting point to have a look at. (Note as of writing it is currently in beta.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am not sure how helpful this will be but check out this slider. It is super simple and has the navigation thumbnails i think you are looking for

http://codetutorial.caroshaw.com/jquery_image_slider.php